# calling a class method from another class

Tags: c++, class, communication

I want to change a variable member of class B, in a method member of class A.
Example:

```
A.h:
class A
{
    //several other things
    void flagchange();
}
A.cpp:
void A::flagchange()
{
    if (human) Bobj.flag=1;
}
```

I know that I need an object of class B, to change a variable member of B, but objects of B are not reachable in A. Is it possible by a pointer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but objects of B are not reachable in A

If objects of class B are not reachable by class A there's no way you can modify them. Once you refactored your design, you should pass it as an argument to the function:

```
class A {
    //several other things
    void flagchange(B& obj) {
        if (human)
            obj.flag = 1;
    }
};
```

> I want to be able to toggle the flag from a method of class A for every object of B

You should declare your `flag` public variable as `static` in `B`:

```
class B {
public:
    static int flag;
};

int B::flag = 0;
```

And then, from inside `A`:

```
class A {
    //several other things
    void flagchange() {
        if (human)
            B::flag = 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter!! the problem is that I need to be able to do this for all of the pbjects of B! So that means that I should have pointers to all of B objects??

Comment: "Unless you register them yourself" what do you mean?

Comment: Is there any other way of changing a variable of class B, in a method of class A???

Comment: a public variable declared in B.h
B.h:
class B
{
    public:
    flag;
}

Comment: of every object.. every object of class B has an instance of this flag variable. I want to be able to toggle the flag from a method of class A for every object of B